# StructureMap Constructor Injection without Interface?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, interface, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I'm setting up a MVC project.  It looks like this

```
EfDbContext : IDbContext { ... }

MyStuff : IMyStuff { ... }

MyService : IMyService {
   List<things> GetSomething(IDbContext context, IMyStuff stuff) { ... }
}

MyController : Controller { 
   ActionResult MyAction(IMyService service) { ... }
}
```

I use StructureMap.MVC to resolve all the constructor dependencies, plus setter injection for auditing and logging in custom ActionFilters.  The only thing I have to manually specify in the IoC is the connection string for IDbContext, everything else just automagically worked!

Until I read some [articles](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/02/Interfacesarenotabstractions/) that says, it smells to have 1:1 ratio between class and interface.  My application is quite simple, there will never be different implementation of IMyStuff or IMyService.  The only reason I have them is so that they can be injected and unit tested (I used Rhino but start to like NSubstitue).

Is there way I can get rid of the interface and inject the concrete class directly?  So it looks like

```
GetSomething(IDbContext context, MyStuff stuff) {}
MyAction(MyService service) {}
```

Of course, I still want all the convention based auto wiring with StructureMap, so I don't have to specify them one by one.

Thanks.

Comment: Upon further testing, it seems StructureMap.MVC has no problem injecting anything.  The concrete class in constructor parameters are injected without even manually config.  But mocking during test seems to be the problem.  Without interface, I have to mark all method virtual, and also specify constructor parameters in test.  There are some arguments about this making test more vulnerable.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: As I understand it, you shouldn't just replace interfaces with concrete classes because having a 1:1 ratio of interfaces and classes is bad. What I hear Mark saying is that having a 1:1 ratio means that you have an architectural problem in your application, using poor abstractions. Read his [follow up post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/03/Towardsbetterabstractions/) for some examples on how to improve the design.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  That's the exact article that bring me to the question.  My applications are usually simple, there will never be a different implementation of the same service.  Even the IDbContext, I have no intention of having anything other than EfDbcontext.  So the interfaces are there just for IoC and Unit test mocking, rather than abstraction.  I read about you can mark everything virtual and mock the class, but there are disagreement there too.  So I'm not really sure what I can do differently.

Comment: Well one common thing that can need abstractions is cross cutting concerns, such as logging, authorization, caching, etc. A common way to solve such concerns is to use the Decorator pattern, effectively introducing a second implementation of the interface. Do you have if statements in your code? [Enter polymorphism](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/08/clean-code-talks-inheritance-polymorphism-testing/) == multiple implementations of an interface/base class.

Comment: I used Agatha RRSL in my last project, which use "interceptor" to add cross cutting stuff. It also has service/client caching built-in. All requests are basically polymorphic base request, so you can batch an array of different requests in one round trip. Pretty neat. Too bad it's kind of dormant. I'm using custom Filters for those in my current MVC project. I know it's still kind of implementation rather than abstraction. But I doubt I'll have a different implementation for any of those. Once done it's done. Anyway, seems I'm stuck with Everything:IEverything just for IoC and Unit Testing?